# Detecting changes in Textfield swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want when user change in textfield a specific `func` will be called. I tried the is code but it did not work:

```
TextField("Search barcode number here", text: $SearchText).onChange(of: SearchText, perform: { newValue in
           orderViewModel.fictchItem(ItemId: newValue)})
```

Is there any other way I can detect the change in text Field?

Thank you!

Comment: It should work so an issue is somewhere else. Provide minimal reproducible example to debug.

Comment: Works fine if I replace orderViewModel.fictchItem(ItemId: newValue) with print

Comment: It's probably a problem with your function then... if print works, then the .onChange 100% is working.